# What is 次第 doing in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> 先日の会議の内容は、後ほど書面にてご報告する次第です。

I think the sentence means something along the lines of: "As for the contents of the meeting the other day, it will be reported in writing later."

But this kinda ignores the 次第です...

I'm used to thinking of 次第だ as meaning "depending on", but I don't see how it fits here.  Looking in a dictionary, I see that 次第 can also mean "as soon as" when used with verbs, but that also seems off.

Any hints on what the 次第 means in this context?

Answer (score 2):

〜という状況です」「〜といういきさつです」といった物事や事柄の事情や由来の説明の意味
[enter link description here](https://eigobu.jp/magazine/shidai)